# I'm a muslim who wasn't tought how to pray and knew nothing until now, but I want to change. How do I start?

Tags: practical-islam, prayer-timings

I was never tought anything about Islam. I know only the basics, like what's haram and what's not. I feel like it was a mistake that i never prayed and all of it.What do I need to start and how do I pray? I can't speak arabic, is it a problem?

Comment: Not knowing Arabic will inshallah not be a major issue. Is there a masjid nearby where you live? Do you have access to the Imam? (Apologies I can't guess your gender from your username)

Comment: I think so, I'm all new to this so I don't really know. (I'm a female)

Comment: You should start slow sister. Don't overburden yourself. If you have access to an Islamic center nearby, there will be other sisters who will inshallah be very happy to help you. Alternately, there are many online resources you can refer to. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8tcIy91OpU)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/T4auGhmeBlw | I reckon that you will appreciate this video

Answer (score 0):

You can go to masjid if it's near your house
You can watch youtube some channels I recommend are iloveyouallah, mufti menk, dijital ummah and etc.
You can start reading quran. You can start the quran by your own language if your not familiar with arabic.